# SQL Server : query to display new column containing data * factor based on previous record

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to formulate a query in SQL Server where:

```
Date        |   Name  | Amount | AmountX
------------+---------+--------+-------
2010-01-01  |   Test  | 0      | 0
2010-02-01  |   Test  | 0      | 0
2010-03-01  |   Test  | 0      | 0
2011-01-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 63.86
2011-02-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 63.86
2011-03-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 63.86
2012-01-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 65.14
2012-02-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 65.14
2012-03-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 65.14
2013-01-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 66.44
2013-02-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 66.44
2013-03-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 66.44
2014-01-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 67.77
2014-02-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 67.77
2014-03-01  |   Test  | 62.61  | 67.77
2015-01-01  |   Test  | 0      | 0
2015-02-01  |   Test  | 0      | 0
2015-03-01  |   Test  | 0      | 0
2016-01-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 69.31
2016-02-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 69.31
2016-03-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 69.31
2017-01-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 70.70
2017-02-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 70.70
2017-03-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 70.70
2018-01-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 72.11
2018-02-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 72.11
2018-03-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 72.11
2019-01-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 73.55
2019-02-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 73.55
2019-03-01  |   Test  | 67.95  | 73.55
```

The Date, Name and Amount columns come from the table.

I need to create a query to include to AmountX column based on the Date grouping.  The Amount and a factor of 2% for calculation.

Year 2010 can be ignored because the Amount values are 0s.

For the year 2011, the Amount values are none 0s which is 62.61.  I need to multiply that by 1.02 giving 63.86, for the whole year and display it in the AmountX column.

Now for the year 2012, it will be calculated 63.86 for previous year X 1.02 = 65.14.

So for 2013, it will be 64.14 X 1.02 = 66.44.

And for 2014, it will be 66.44 X 1.02 = 67.77.

Is this doable?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

RS..

Comment: have you tried using `LAG` window function?

Comment: I tired.  But the issue I am having is with the resulting AmountX which will be the based of the next calculation.

Comment: what's the actual sample data look like? I'm guessing the amount column isn't populated?

Comment: Actually, the data source is really based on a query.  It contain the Date, Name and Amount only.  So say when the records of the year contain 0s, the calculation for the next year starts over by using the value in Amount in that year's X 1.02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t.*, 
       (amount * power(1.02, year(date) - 2010)) as amountX
from t;
```

Comment: Sorry.  My bad.  Actually the date is not part of the calculation.  It is there as a grouping.

Comment: @RickshaW . . . I don't understand.  This seems to be the calculation you want.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the help.  The actual calculation for the AmountX does not involved the date.  Date is there for grouping to determine when to start new calculation.  Really, calculation is based solely on the Amount column and the 1st month of the year.  The hard part which I still cannot figure out is how to get the running amount in of the AmountX's for use as a  base amount to calculate the next year's amount.  You help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Gordon.  Actually, your are right.  Your solution worked.  I had more time to incorporate it and with a some tweak in my whole query, got it working.  Thanks so much.